# Async FromBeginEnd interface

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I have following C# async interface:

```
x.BeginOperation(a:sting, b:string, c:string, d:string, g:string, ?q:string) : IAsyncResult
x.EndOperation(result:IAsyncResult) : IEnumerable<string>
```

I would like to use this in my async workflow and get `Async<'T>` object that would represent the computation.

I guess that Async.FromBeginEnd is the way to go but I have hard time trying to pass begin/end operation method to it. BeginOperation has too many arguments plus the optional one (plus I don't really manage to wrap my mind around the AsyncCallback * obj in signature).

What is the proper way to get Async from this interface. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your interface is declared something like this:

```
type IMyInterface =
    abstract member BeginOperation :
        (string * string * string * string * string * string option) ->
        IAsyncResult
    abstract member EndOperation : IAsyncResult -> string seq
```

you should be able to create an `Async<'T>` using a little helper function like this:

```
let toAsync (x : IMyInterface) =
    let beginAction (callback, values : obj) =
        match values with
        | :? (string * string * string * string * string * string option) as v ->
            x.BeginOperation v
        | _ -> failwith "Unexpected values"

    Async.FromBeginEnd (beginAction, x.EndOperation)
```

The inner `beginAction` helper function has the signature `'a * obj -> IAsyncResult`, which means that it takes a tuple of the generic type `'a` (in C# it would typically be denoted as `T`) and a `System.Object`, and returns an `IAsyncResult` instance.

For `Async.FromBeginEnd`, that's the required signature for the `beginAction`.

The interface's `EndOperation` method already has the correct signature, so it can be passed in unmodified.

The entire signature of the `toAsync` function is `IMyInterface -> Async<seq<string>>`.

Comment: I see. The :? (string * string * string * string * string * string option) as v did the trick. Thanks.